# Identificar client WCF Service (intranet ou internet)

Tags: c#, wcf

Gostaria de saber se é possível identificar a chamada se um WCF Service no servidor, se a mesma foi chamada por um client dentro da rede (intranet) ou fora da rede (internet).

Estou implementando uma compactação de dados a serem trafegados, mas se o consumo foi na rede irei trafegar sem compactação.

Tenho caso que o cliente usa um notebook, quando está na empresa está na rede (intranet), mas quando vai pra casa, consome o serviço usando a internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com WCF é possível identificar o endereço IP do cliente que está conectado no seu serviço, através da propriedade [`RemoteEndpointMessageProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.servicemodel.channels.remoteendpointmessageproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). A partir do IP você pode usar alguma regra baseado na subnet para decidir se a chamada está vindo a partir da Intranet ou se é uma chamada externa.

Comment: Obrigado Carlos, implementei a identificação, agora vou partir para os cálculos de subnet.